# Removing Default Paragraph Symbol from Richtext CQ Component

Tags: aem, richtext

I've a richtext CQ component. On dropping it to the page, ¶-symbol is displayed till I configure any text into the component. I want to show some default text instead. For eg:- "Click here to set text". Then on opening the configuration dialogue, the default etxt should go off. Please help

Answer (score 0):

copy the component at /libs/foundation/components/text and  replace line number 20 in /libs/foundation/components/text/text.jsp with

```
<cq:text property="text" placeholder="click here to set text"/>
```

for more check out this [link](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/taglib.html)

Comment: The way I'm using the text component is following:-
On my page i've incuded a component as 

    <cq:include path="content-article" resourceType="ceb/webcq/components/content/text/articletext" />

The articletext component doesn't have any jsp. Its simply a configuration dialogue. How should I proceed in this case?